# Issue to set map in center so multiple marker display

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, fitbounds

i am using ionic framework. i created map and multiple markers and value came from server side.all data came properly but i don't know why i getting this error-

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'fitBounds' of null
    at autoCenter (app.js:147)
    at app.js:135
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
    at ionic.bundle.js:27895
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:23676)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:23848)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:23789)
```

code :
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, GoogleMaps) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    GoogleMaps.init();
  });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('map', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})
.factory('Markers', function ($http) {

    var markers = [];

    return {
        getMarkers: function () {

            return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/LocationServices/markers.php").then(function (response) {
                markers = response;
                return markers;
            });

        }
    }

})

.factory('GoogleMaps', function ($cordovaGeolocation, Markers) {

    var apiKey = false;
    var map = null;
    var zoomVal = 15

    function initMap() {

        var options = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            console.log("Latitude current: ", position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("Longitude current: ", position.coords.longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: zoomVal,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            //Wait until the map is loaded
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: latLng
                });
                //Load the markers
                loadMarkers(map);
                //map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25));

            });

        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Could not get location");

            //Load the markers
            loadMarkers(map);
            //map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25));
        });

    }

    function loadMarkers(map) {

        //Get all of the markers from our Markers factory
        Markers.getMarkers().then(function (markers) {

            console.log("Markers: ", markers);
            var markersss = new Array();

            var records = markers.data.markers;

            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

                var record = records[i];
                console.log("Latitude: ", record.lat);
                console.log("Longitude: ", record.lng);
                var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record.lat, record.lng);
                console.log("marker position", "" + markerPos);

                // Add the markerto the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: markerPos
                });

                markersss.push(marker);

                var infoWindowContent = "<h4>" + record.name + "</h4>";

                addInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent, record);

            }
            autoCenter(map, markersss);
        });
    }
    function autoCenter(map1, markersss) {
        //Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //Go through each...
        for (var i = 0; i < markersss.length; i++) {
            bounds.extend(markersss[i].position);
            console.log("bounds position", "" + markersss[i].position);
        }
        //Fit these bounds to the map
        map1.fitBounds(bounds);
        map1.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        //remove one zoom level to ensure no marker is on the edge.
        map1.setZoom(vm.googleMap.getZoom() - 1);

        // set a minimum zoom
        // if you got only 1 marker or all markers are on the same address map will be zoomed too much.
        if (map1.getZoom() > zoomVal) {
            map1.setZoom(zoomVal);
        }
    }
    function addInfoWindow(marker, message, record) {

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: message
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

    }

    return {
        init: function () {
            initMap();
        }
    }

})

.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {

});
```

Comment: hey guys please help me..i am stuck

Comment: in browser didn't  see,but when i run into mobile map display

Comment: now my map display properly. but problem is that it display in mozilla browser. in chrome it display error. why this is happened??

Comment: chrome requires a secure connection ( https ) for the usage of geolocation

Comment: when i switch http to https then i get error  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

The `map` will only be created when `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition` was successfull, but you also call `loadMarkers` when it wasn't successfull(map is `null` in this case)

Solution: create the map outside of the `getCurrentPosition`-callbacks (with a default-value for center).

In the success-callback create the `marker` and set the `center` of the map

```
function initMap() {

    var options     = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true },
        mapOptions  = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92,151.25),
                        zoom: zoomVal,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                      },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

      $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

        var center =   new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude, 
                                               position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(center);
        new google.maps.Marker({
                map       : map,
                animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position  : center
            });
        loadMarkers(map);           

      }, function (error) {
        loadMarkers(map);
      });

    });
}
```

Comment: sorry i am beginner in this. so if u have no issue then give example..thank you